# react inner component's state change don't smooth

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to control inputs with state.

But I'm having a problem with this case which input keep losing it's focus when I hit the keyboard.

See picture below:

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-solve-this-7kwj6

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onBchange = this.onBchange.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    a: true,
    b: "",
    c: ""
  };

  onBchange(e) {
    const thisClass = this;
    return (async function() {
      await thisClass.setState({ b: e.target.value });
      console.log(thisClass.state.b);
    })();
  }

  onCchange = e => {
    this.setState({ c: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    // this cause problem why?
    const Test = ({ b, c, onBchange, onCchange }) => (
      <Fragment>
        <span>B: </span>
        <input value={b} onChange={onBchange} />
        <span>C: </span>
        <input value={c} onChange={onCchange} />
      </Fragment>
    );

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.a && (
          <Test
            b={this.state.b}
            c={this.state.c}
            onBchange={this.onBchange}
            onCchange={this.onCchange}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more info about this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is rerendering those elements on each change because each keystroke causes new props to be passed to `<Test/>` within your App's render method.

Notice that changing the return method in render to this stops the issue:

```
 <div className="App">
        <span>B: </span>
        <input value={this.state.b} onChange={this.onBchange} />
        <span>C: </span>
        <input value={this.state.c} onChange={this.onCchange} />
        {/* {this.state.a && (
          <Test
            b={this.state.b}
            c={this.state.c}
            onBchange={this.onBchange}
            onCchange={this.onCchange}
          />
        )} */}
      </div>
```